# Does how I spread out Push-Ups through out the day matter?

Tags: push-ups, exercise-frequency

So, case 1: I do 20 push-ups every two hours until I have a total of 100 push-ups. Or, case 2: I do 100 push-ups in one session. I take a breather every few push-ups, but I do reach my 100 total, but this time within the span of about an hour. Is there a difference between me doing each case? Which one is more beneficial for me to do?